# Please advise if I should rollback this revision:

Tags: discussion, edits, revisions-list, rollbacks

Please check [this revision](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/18620571/revisions).

The new question title seems a bit ironical to me. But I'm not a native speaker (surprise!), so I may be nitpicking.

Can I rollback?

Comment: So, counter a silly title edit with an even more silly rollback?

Comment: @animuson, that's why I'm asking here. It was not clear for me how silly it is. :-)

Comment: @Ferdinand.kraft aren't editors supposed to leave posts alone when they are uncertain of contents, edits, or both ? Of course, better to ask too, but ... (I'm not blasting you, just wondering if you're being OverEnglishZealous () ; :))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope, the title is just fine, there is no need to roll the edit back.

The editor replaced "How to extract capture group" with the shorter "Extract capture group". The verb "To extract" has no ironic meaning in this context. I suspect he did this to make the title fit on one line.

What ironic meaning did *you* read in *"Extract capture group matches from regular expressions?"* exactly?

At best, the edit was a little unnecessary, but rolling it back again would not gain you anything either. I'd just leave it be.

Comment: It sounded to me as if I was certain it is not possible, and posing the question anyway. Rhetorical. Thanks for your patience. Things are clear now.

Comment: @Ferdinand.kraft: Nope; I'm sure the title does not carry that meaning.

Answer (score 3):

You can if you feel that your version is preferable, although I also don't see a compelling reason you would *need* to do a rollback either.

Looking at the edit I think it's rather odd.  It makes the title grammatically a statement, not a question (due to the removal of "how to") but the question mark was left.  I'd expect, if the editor wanted to change it from a question to a statement he'd want to remove that as well.

In any case, I don't see anything really *wrong* with your version.  If there was a significant problem being fixed, and you rolled it back, that would be bad.  This is something that falls more into the "personal preference" category, and for that, you have more weight as you are the original author.

Comment: Well, `How to <do x>` is still a statement, just like `<do x>` is a statement. `How do I <do x>?` would be a question.